# List all the folder and files of Dropbox using Dropbox API not working

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've tried to create a file.
my app hangs in the line

```
 List<DbxFileInfo> infos = dbxFs.listFolder(DbxPath.ROOT);
```

Here is my log Message: (I replace IP * * * . * * * . * * * .* * *)

```
    10-23 09:11:39.330: I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor(4486): Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/***.***.***.***,port=443,localPort=45370]
10-23 09:11:41.200: E/libDropboxSync.so(err)(4486): client.cpp:79: bad_state: This app is not allowed to use the Sync API for file access.
10-23 09:11:42.200: I/libDropboxSync.so(cache)(4486): client.cpp:107: fetching access info
10-23 09:11:42.400: I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor(4486): Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/***.***.***.***,port=443,localPort=43962]
10-23 09:11:44.850: E/libDropboxSync.so(err)(4486): client.cpp:79: bad_state: This app is not allowed to use the Sync API for file access.
10-23 09:11:45.850: I/libDropboxSync.so(cache)(4486): client.cpp:107: fetching access info
10-23 09:11:46.060: I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor(4486): Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/***.***.***.***,port=443,localPort=50441]
10-23 09:11:47.600: W/libDropboxSync.so(thr)(4486): env.cpp:139: int dropbox_wait_for_first_sync(dbx_client*) should not be called on the main thread
10-23 09:11:50.530: E/libDropboxSync.so(err)(4486): client.cpp:79: bad_state: This app is not allowed to use the Sync API for file access.
10-23 09:11:51.530: I/libDropboxSync.so(cache)(4486): client.cpp:107: fetching access info
10-23 09:11:51.750: I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor(4486): Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/***.***.***.***,port=443,localPort=33341]
10-23 09:11:53.120: E/libDropboxSync.so(err)(4486): client.cpp:79: bad_state: This app is not allowed to use the Sync API for file access.
10-23 09:11:54.120: I/libDropboxSync.so(cache)(4486): client.cpp:107: fetching access info
10-23 09:11:54.330: I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor(4486): Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/***.***.***.***,port=443,localPort=39033]
```

My java class:

```
 public class DropBoxCLAplication {
    public static  DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;
    private static final String TAG = IBMCLAplication.class.getSimpleName();
    private DbxFileSystem.PathListener m_observer;
    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0; 
    DbxFileSystem dbxFs;
    DbxFile dbFile;
    private DbxFileSystem.SyncStatusListener m_syncstatus;
    private DbxDatastoreManager mAccountManager;
    public DropBoxCLAplication( DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr){
    try {   

        dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

       mAccountManager = DbxDatastoreManager.localManager(mDbxAcctMgr);
       mAccountManager.openDefaultDatastore();
          m_observer = new DbxFileSystem.PathListener() {

            public void onPathChange(DbxFileSystem dbxFileSystem, final DbxPath dbxPath, Mode mode) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Sync change detected on dropbox, reloading " + dbxPath.getName());

                try {
                    DbxFile fInfo = dbxFileSystem.open(dbxPath);
                    final boolean latest = fInfo.getSyncStatus().isLatest;
                    fInfo.close();
                    Log.v(TAG, "File " + dbxPath.getName() + " changed. Latest: " + latest);

                    dbxFileSystem.addSyncStatusListener(new DbxFileSystem.SyncStatusListener() {

                        public void onSyncStatusChange(DbxFileSystem dbxFileSystem) {
                            try {
                                DbxSyncStatus status = dbxFileSystem.getSyncStatus();
                                if (!status.anyInProgress()) {
                                    // If we got triggered because of local changes we are already at latest version
                                    // Otherwise we call the refresh callback
                                    if (!latest) {

                                    }
                                    dbxFileSystem.removeSyncStatusListener(this);
                                }
                            } catch (DbxException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        m_syncstatus = new DbxFileSystem.SyncStatusListener() {


           public void onSyncStatusChange(DbxFileSystem dbxFileSystem) {
               DbxSyncStatus status = null;
               try {
                   status = dbxFileSystem.getSyncStatus();
                   if (status.anyInProgress()) {

                   } else {

                   }
               } catch (DbxException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       };
       dbxFs.addSyncStatusListener(m_syncstatus);

        dbxFs.addPathListener(m_observer, DbxPath.ROOT, DbxFileSystem.PathListener.Mode.PATH_ONLY);

        doDropboxTest( dbxFs);
        Log.i(TAG,dbxFs.getSyncStatus().isSyncActive+"");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         Log.e(TAG,"DropBoxCLAplication error  "+e.toString()); 
    }

    }


    private void doDropboxTest(DbxFileSystem dbxFs) {
       try {
           final String TEST_DATA = "Hello Dropbox";
           final String TEST_FILE_NAME = "hello_dropbox.txt";
           DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, TEST_FILE_NAME);

           // Create DbxFileSystem for synchronized file access.

           // Print the contents of the root folder.  This will block until we can
           // sync metadata the first time.
           List<DbxFileInfo> infos = dbxFs.listFolder(DbxPath.ROOT);
           Log.i(TAG,"\nContents of app folder:\n");
           for (DbxFileInfo info : infos) {
             Log.i(TAG,"    " + info.path + ", " + info.modifiedTime + '\n');
           }

           // Create a test file only if it doesn't already exist.
           if (!dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
               DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.create(testPath);
               try {
                   testFile.writeString(TEST_DATA);
               } finally {
                   testFile.close();
               }
               Log.i(TAG,"\nCreated new file '" + testPath + "'.\n");
           }

           // Read and print the contents of test file.  Since we're not making
           // any attempt to wait for the latest version, this may print an
           // older cached version.  Use getSyncStatus() and/or a listener to
           // check for a new version.
           if (dbxFs.isFile(testPath)) {
               String resultData;
               DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
               try {
                   resultData = testFile.readString();
               } finally {
                   testFile.close();
               }
               Log.i(TAG,"\nRead file '" + testPath + "' and got data:\n    " + resultData);
           } else if (dbxFs.isFolder(testPath)) {
             Log.i(TAG,"'" + testPath.toString() + "' is a folder.\n");
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Dropbox test failed: " + e);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The error is "This app is not allowed to use the Sync API for file access." The most common cause is trying to use an app key that has "Full Dropbox" permission, which is not compatible with the Sync API. You'll need to create an app with either "File type" or "App folder" permissions.